I want to scrape links of companies hidden under _doPostBack links
I have this website(https://www.nfrc.co.uk/search-members), I want to click on "Search for a roofing contractor now" then For a Domestic Property and then Search. A lot of pages appear, I just need links hidden under all the company names and navigate through all the pages. I have no coding background. It would be appreciated if someone provides me the python code to scrape these links.
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
import time

# Setup Chrome options
chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_argument("--start-maximized")  # Maximize the browser window

# Initialize Selenium WebDriver using ChromeDriverManager
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=webdriver.chrome.service.Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()), options=chrome_options)

# Initialize an empty list to store company data
company_data = []

# Function to wait and click with retry
def wait_and_click(driver, by, value, retries=3):
for _ in range(retries):
    try:
        element = WebDriverWait(driver,20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((by, value)))
        driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", element)
        element.click()
        return True
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error clicking element {value}: {e}")
        time.sleep(2)  # Wait before retrying
return False

    # Open the NFRC website
driver.get("https://www.nfrc.co.uk/search-members")

    # Click on "Search for a roofing contractor now"
wait_and_click(driver, By.LINK_TEXT, "Search for a roofing contractor now")

    # Click to open the dropdown for contractor type selection
 dropdown_locator = (By.CLASS_NAME, "sfDropdownList")
 wait_and_click(driver, By.CLASS_NAME, "sfDropdownList")

    # Select "For a Domestic Property" from the dropdown
 wait_and_click(driver, By.XPATH, '//[@id="MainContent_C001_contractorType"]/option[@value="CONTRACTOR_ADVANCED_DOMESTIC_PROPERTY_VIEW"]')

    # Select "Pitched Roof"
wait_and_click(driver, By.XPATH, '//*[@id="MainContent_C001_rblRoofType"]/li[1]/label')

    # Proceed to the next step
wait_and_click(driver, By.ID, "MainContent_C001_btnSearch")

    # Add a delay to ensure the page loads completely after 
clicking search button
time.sleep(5)  # Adjust the time delay as needed

I have tried this code, it works until listings appear and further I don't have idea.

Did you use ChatGPT or another AI to generate the code in question?

Yes I used ChatGPT.

This should get you most of the way there.
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
import time

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("--start-maximized")

driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=webdriver.chrome.service.Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()), options=chrome_options)

def wait_and_click(driver, by, value, retries=3):
    for _ in range(retries):
        try:
            element = WebDriverWait(driver,20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((by, value)))
            driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", element)
            element.click()
            return True
        except Exception as e:
            print(f"Error clicking element {value}: {e}")
            time.sleep(2)
    return False

driver.get("https://www.nfrc.co.uk/search-members")

wait_and_click(driver, By.LINK_TEXT, "Search for a roofing contractor now")

wait_and_click(driver, By.CLASS_NAME, "sfDropdownList")

wait_and_click(driver, By.XPATH, '//option[@value="CONTRACTOR_ADVANCED_DOMESTIC_PROPERTY_VIEW"]')

wait_and_click(driver, By.ID, "MainContent_C001_btnSearch")

WebDriverWait(driver,20).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".search_results")))

while True:
    index = 0

    # Can't just iterate over list of elements because when return to page these elements are stale.
    #
    while True:
        results = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "h3 > a")

        try:
            results[index].click()
        except IndexError:
            # Exhausted all results on page.
            break

        try:
            link = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#ctl00_MainContent_C004_radListView_ctrl0_tr4 td.details_item > a")
            print(link.get_attribute("href"))
        except NoSuchElementException:
            # No URL on contractor page.
            pass

        # Return to search results.
        driver.back()

        index += 1

    paginate = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#ctl00_MainContent_C001_radListView_radDataPager1 a")

    for next in range(len(paginate)):
        page = paginate[next]
        if page.get_attribute("onclick") == "return false;":
            print("⏩ Move to next page!")
            paginate[next+1].click()
            break

driver.close()

This is what the output looks like for first few pages of search results:
http://www.1stchoiceroofingbristol.co.uk/                                                                                                                                                                                               
https://www.1stroofingltd.co.uk/                                                                                                                                                                                                        
https://www.3aroofing.co.uk/                                                                                                                                                                                                            
http://www.aeelkins.co.uk/                                                                                                                                                                                                              
⏩ Move to next page!                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
https://www.armstrongroofing.expert/                                                                                                                                                                                                    
https://www.acwhyte.co.uk/                                                                                                                                                                                                              
https://www.adlangandsons.co.uk/                                                                                                                                                                                                        
https://www.aehughes.com/                                                                                                                                                                                                               
https://www.aj-developments.co.uk/                                                                                                                                                                                                      
⏩ Move to next page!                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
https://www.alkingroofing.co.uk/                                                                                                                                                                                                        
http://www.sneddonroofing.co.uk/                                                                                                                                                                                                        
https://www.taylorroofing.co.uk/                                                                                                                                                                                                        
https://www.awilsonroofing.co.uk/                                                                                                                                                                                                       
https://www.aaharrisonandsons.co.uk/                                                                                                                                                                                                    
⏩ Move to next page!                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
https://www.abaulroofing.com/                                                                                                                                                                                                           
https://abcroofinglimited.co.uk/                                                                                                                                                                                                        
http://www.absroofing.co.uk/                                                                                                                                                                                                            
https://www.aesroofing.co.uk/                                                                                                                                                                                                           
http://www.a1feltroofing.co.uk/                                                                                                                                                                                                         
⏩ Move to next page!                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
https://www.a1roofspec.co.uk/                                                                                                                                                                                                           
https://www.aaaroofing.co.uk/                                                                                                                                                                                                           
https://www.abbeyroofing.co.uk/                                                                                                                                                                                                         
https://www.abbeymillhomes.co.uk/                                                                                                                                                                                                       
http://www.acroofingservices.co.uk/                                                                                                                                                                                                     
⏩ Move to next page!

I see that you included pandas, so presumably you'll want to accumulate the URLs and then create a Data Frame at the end, possibly dumping that to a CSV file.
Also, the main pagination loop still needs a clean exit point. I didn't have time to wait for it to iterate through all of the result pages. You should catch whatever exceptional event arises and then exit cleanly from the infinite pagination loop.

Thank you so much for providing me with this code. It worked like a charm and was incredibly helpful :)
